# Run multiple spiders from script in scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I am doing scrapy project I want run multiple spiders at a time 
This is code for run spiders from script. I getting error .. how to do

```
 from spiders.DmozSpider import DmozSpider
 from spiders.CraigslistSpider import CraigslistSpider

 from scrapy import signals, log
 from twisted.internet import reactor
 from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
 from scrapy.settings import Settings

 TO_CRAWL = [DmozSpider, CraigslistSpider]


 RUNNING_CRAWLERS = []

def spider_closing(spider):
"""Activates on spider closed signal"""
log.msg("Spider closed: %s" % spider, level=log.INFO)
RUNNING_CRAWLERS.remove(spider)
if not RUNNING_CRAWLERS:
    reactor.stop()
```

log.start(loglevel=log.DEBUG)
   for spider in TO_CRAWL:
      settings = Settings()

```
 # crawl responsibly
 settings.set("USER_AGENT", "Kiran Koduru (+http://kirankoduru.github.io)")
 crawler = Crawler(settings)
 crawler_obj = spider()
 RUNNING_CRAWLERS.append(crawler_obj)

# stop reactor when spider closes
crawler.signals.connect(spider_closing, signal=signals.spider_closed)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(crawler_obj)
crawler.start()
```

## blocks process so always keep as the last statement

reactor.run()

Comment: Can you improve your code formatting?
What error are you getting? can you provide a traceback?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to *not* answer the question itself but just bringing into your attention [scrapyd](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [scrapinghub](http://scrapinghub.com) (at least for a quick test). `reactor.run()` (when you make it) will run any number of Scrapy instances on a single CPU. Do you want this side effect? Even if you have a look on `scrapyd`'s code, they don't run multiple instances with a single thread but they do [fork/spawn subprocesses](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/blob/master/scrapyd/launcher.py#L48).

Answer (score 2):

You need something like the code below. You can easily find it from Scrapy docs :)

> First utility you can use to run your spiders is
>   scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess. This class will start a Twisted reactor
>   for you, configuring the logging and setting shutdown handlers. This
>   class is the one used by all Scrapy commands.

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import logging
import traceback
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from spiders.DmozSpider import DmozSpider
from spiders.CraigslistSpider import CraigslistSpider

SPIDER_LIST = [
    DmozSpider, CraigslistSpider
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        ## set up the crawler and start to crawl one spider at a time
        process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
        for spider in SPIDER_LIST:
            process.crawl(spider)
        process.start()
    except Exception, e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        logging.info('Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno))
        logging.info("Exception: %s" % str(traceback.format_exc()))
```

References:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

Comment: thanks for this but I think this run on single processor . But I have list of 100000 domains I want run 30 instances in AWS EC2 . how to do queue of domains list to run spiders in 30 instances. 30 spiders runs in those 30 instance at a time . How to do

Comment: You can make separated scripts for different instances. Each instances run a set of your spiders. Sorry, but I don't quite get your question.